FastAPI error when using Annotated in Class dependencies
FastAPI added support for Annotated (and started recommending it) in version 0.95.0.
Additionally, FastAPI has a very powerful but intuitive Dependency Injection system (documentation).  Moreover, FastAPI support Classes as Dependencies.
However, it seams like Annotated cannot be used in class dependencies, but on function dependencies.
I use FastAPI version 0.110.1.
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query

app = FastAPI()


class ClassDependency:
    def __init__(self, name: Annotated[str, Query(description="foo")]):
        self.name = name

async def function_dependency(name: Annotated[str, Query(description="foo")]) -> dict:
    return {"name": name}


@app.get("/")
async def search(c: Annotated[ClassDependency, Depends(function_dependency)]) -> dict:
    return {"c": c.name}

The example above works without errors, but if I replace Depends(function_dependency) with Depends(ClassDependency) an exception is raised with the following message:
pydantic.errors.PydanticUndefinedAnnotation: name 'Query' is not defined

Then, if I remove Annotated from the ClassDependency, by replacing the name: Annotated[str, Query(description="foo")] with the name: str, the example works.
My question: Can I use Class dependencies and put Annotated to the parameters set in the constructor? Because it seams this is not working.
My need: I want to have a class hierarchy for the query params of my api endpoints and provide validation and documentation extras for each of the param.

What version of fastapi are you using? It works in 0.110.0 for me. Btw if you are using class dependencies it is enough to say c: Annotated[ClassDependency, Depends()]

I use 0.110.1, I don't think they have break it on their latest patch. Are you sure it works? Did you follow the exact example? Maybe I am missing something.

Remove from __future__ import annotations and it will work

Thanks a lot! Fixed! You may provide it as a solution for anybody else having the same issue.

Remove the following and it will work.
from __future__ import annotations

